# How to remove from any container?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

I'd like to remove certain items from a container.
The problem is, I don't know what kind of container it is.
Most STL-algorithms famously don't care about container: e.g., `find_if`, `copy_if`, etc. all work more or less with any container type.

But what about deleting?
For `vector`-like containers, there is the remove-erase-idiom, which, however, cannot be applied to, e.g., `set`-like containers.
Using template specialization or overloading, I could specialize for particular containers but that does not scale when other containers (`unordered_set`, `list`, ...) should be considered, too.

My question is:
**How to implement a function which removes certain items from any container *efficiently***? Preferred signature:

```
template<typename Ts, typename Predicate>
void remove_if(Ts& ts, const Predicate& p);
```

Or, more concrete: How can I distinguish between `set`-like containers (fast insert/delete, no custom order) and `vector`-like containers (slow insert/delete, custom order)? Is there a (commonly used) container which does not fit in either category?

*Edit:
I just found `std::experimental::erase_if`, which has overloads for many (all?) containers. That is, I will accept a solution only if it doesn't use `std::experimental`.*

Comment: @VTT Yeah, that's what I though first. But does `std::random_access_iterator_tag` guarantee that the remove-erase idiom works?

Comment: there is a reason why the algorithms family in c++ don't include algorithms which change the size of the underlying container...

Comment: @pasbi - you actually only need to consider all possible iterators (traits).

Comment: if you still need to do this, then you could do this based on the traits of iterator

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti I don't want to propose a new algorithm for the standard, I want to implement it for myself. Is there any reason why I shouldn't develop such a routine?

Comment: @uv_ How can I do that? `iterator_traits` don't tell me whether I should use `erase-remove`, `erase` or `remove`. Please tell me if I miss something.

Comment: Re: "Most STL-algorithms famously don't care about container" -- indeed. That's the point. Algorithms operate on **ranges** defined by a pair of **iterators**. Containers are one way of managing ranges, but they are not the only way.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm fine with a `template<...> remove_if(iterator begin, iterator end, P predicate)` signature, too. To me, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @pasbi: Containers are not meant to be interchangeable. You're not expected to be able to write a function that can manipulate any container, outside of basic range functionality (which is primarily about iterators, not container manipulation). So being able to manipulate any container is not really the point.

Comment: @NicolBolas why not? If I have an algorithm which is semantically applicable to any container, why shouldn't there be a routine which does nothing but applying that very algorithm on any container? I believe the standard committee thinks the same way because it proposes such a very routine (`std::experimental::erase_if`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**<sub>Edit:</sub>**

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791992/how-to-remove-from-any-container/53792146?noredirect=1#comment94437428_53792146) by @pasbi, it seems that we already have [`std::experimental::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if), which does exactly that! It will be merged into `std::` in C++20.

If you want a custom implementation, read ahead.

---

You don't have to specialize for specific containers. Instead, you can use type traits and SFINAE to determine container 'category'.

> Is there a (commonly used) container which does not fit in either category?

I'd say yes. There are `std::list` and `std::forward_list` which have `.remove_if()` member function, which should be faster than erase-remove.

---

Thus, we have three possible implementations:

We use `.remove_if()` if it's available (as determined by `std::experimental::is_detected`).
This way we handle `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

Otherwise, we use erase-remove if possible. (Which is possible if container elements are move-assignable, which can be tested with `std::is_move_assignable`.)
This way we handle all remaining standard containers except for `std::[unordered_]map` and `std::[unordered_]set`. (This is what you call `vector`-like containers.)

Otherwise we resort to a simple erasing loop over the elements.
This way we handle `std::[unordered_]map` and `std::[unordered_]set`.

---

Example implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <utility>

inline auto dummy_predicate = [](auto &&){return false;};

template <typename T> using detect_member_remove_if =
    decltype(std::declval<T&>().remove_if(dummy_predicate));

template <typename T, typename F> void remove_if(T &container, F &&func)
{
    using element_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(container))>;

    if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected_v<detect_member_remove_if, T>)
    {
        container.remove_if(std::forward<F>(func));
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_move_assignable_v<element_t>)
    {
        auto new_end = std::remove_if(std::begin(container), std::end(container),
                                      std::forward<F>(func));
        container.erase(new_end, std::end(container));
    }
    else
    {
        auto it = std::begin(container);
        while (it != std::end(container))
        {
            if (func(*it))
                it = container.erase(it);
            else
                it++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

> I'd prefer something without `experimental`

Here's a custom replacement for `std::experimental::is_detected_v`:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename ...P> struct void_impl {using type = void;};
    template <typename ...P> using void_t = typename void_impl<P...>::type;

    template <typename Dummy, template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
    struct is_detected : std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
    struct is_detected<void_t<A<B...>>, A, B...> : std::true_type {};
}

template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
inline constexpr bool is_detected_v = impl::is_detected<void, A, B...>::value;
```

Note that we don't use C++17 `std::void_t` because, as far as I know, it still doesn't SFINAE correctly in Clang.

Comment: Nice! I didn't consider the experimental stuff. Unfortunately, while browsing the documentation about experimental, I found `std::experimental::erase_if`, which does pretty much what I require out of the box. I'd prefer something without experimental, however.

Comment: @pasbi - if you want you can implement is_dtected_v yourself....the implementation is here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected

Comment: I'm not completely content. It's a lot of boilerplate code. But, of course, it meets the requirements. I'll accept it because you told me that `list`-, `vector`- and `set`-like is equivalent to 'has `remove_if`', 'iterator `is_move_assignable`' and 'otherwise'

Comment: @pasbi It's not "boilerplate". It's three functions in one, so that you catch all the cases and never need to write it again.

Answer (score 2):

`std::erase` and `std::erase_if` will be part of C++20. See [P1209](https://wg21.link/P1209)

Libc++ (trunk) implements this already (as of yesterday :-)), and it will be part of clang 8.0.